# ArrayBlockingQueue: concurrent put and take

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, lock-free

I have implemented an `ArrayBlockingQueue` (put and take) on the lines of `LinkedBlockingQueue` i.e using two locks so that my take should not block my put.

For more information please see this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015571/arrayblockingqueue-uses-a-single-lock-for-insertion-and-removal-but-linkedblocki).  The code is also available at [GitHub](https://github.com/lazysun/concurrency/blob/master/Concurrency/src/com/ipenned/queue/ArrayBlockingQueue.java).

Please review the code for any race conditions.

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class ArrayBlockingQueue<T> {

    private final int capacity;
    private final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0); 
    private final Lock putLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Lock takeLock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition notEmpty = takeLock.newCondition(); // putLock will signal that its not empty
    private final Condition notFull = putLock.newCondition(); // signal when queue is notFull
    private final Object [] items ;
    int takeIndex;
    int putIndex;

    public ArrayBlockingQueue(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        items = new Object[capacity];

    }

    public void add(T t) throws InterruptedException {
        int c = -1;
        final Lock lock = this.putLock;
        final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while(count.get() == capacity) {
                    notFull.await();
            }
            enqueue(t);
            c = count.getAndIncrement();
            if(c+1 < capacity) {
                notFull.signal();
            }
        }finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        if(c == 0) {
            signalNotEmpty();
        }
    }

    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        int c = -1;
        final Lock lock = this.takeLock;
        final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
        T t = null;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while(count.get() == 0) {
                notEmpty.await();
            }
            t = dequeue();
            c = count.getAndDecrement();
            if(c > 1) {
                notEmpty.signal();
            }
        }finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
        if(c == capacity) {
            signalNotFull();
        }
        return t;
    }

    private void signalNotEmpty() {
        final Lock lock = this.takeLock;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            notEmpty.signal();
        }finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private void signalNotFull() {
        final Lock lock = this.putLock;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            notFull.signal();
        }finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private T dequeue() {
        final Object[] items = this.items;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T x = (T) items[takeIndex];
        items[takeIndex] = null;
        if (++takeIndex == items.length)
            takeIndex = 0;
        return x;
    }


    private void enqueue(T t) {
        final Object[] items = this.items;
        items[putIndex] = t;
        if (++putIndex == items.length)
            putIndex = 0;
    }


}
```

Comment: @jamal thanks for editing, post looks better now

Comment: Hi. Have you checked the Javadoc for Condition? It has a straightforward implementation of a BoundedBuffer, which I believe is what you're looking for (just need to parameterize the capacity).

Comment: @Elegie Hi, now the example in javadoc for condition is again using a single lock. whereas my implementation is specifically using separate locks for put and take i.e. is the main thing i wanted to verify

Comment: If you haven't already done so, you should look at Disruptor; which similarly uses a shared ring buffer as a queue (but tuned for a different set of use cases).  https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason thanks,yes in my current project we are already using Disruptor

Answer (score 3):

### Typo

In your `take()` function, you wrote this:

```
            notFull.signal();
```

But I'm pretty sure you meant to write this:

```
            notEmpty.signal();
```

### Unnecessary Signalling? Nope

Originally, I thought that the extra signalling in the `add()` and `take()` functions were unnecessary.  In fact, they are not required, but when they are added, it improves performance.  It is a concept called "cascading notifies".  The [LinkedBlockingQueue sources](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/harmony/standard/classlib/trunk/modules/concurrent/src/main/java/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.java)  explain it like this:

> Also, to minimize need for puts to get takeLock and vice-versa, cascading notifies are used. When a put notices that it has enabled at least one take, it signals taker. That taker in turn signals others if more items have been entered since the signal. And symmetrically for takes signalling puts.

### Race condition? Nope

Originally, I thought that the code had a race condition involving memory reordering when accessing the shared queue.  However, it was pointed out that `AtomicInteger` acts as a volatile variable and provides a memory barrier.  So therefore the accesses are safe.

### Update

After reading @rolfl's answer with his multiple variants that attempt to improve upon the original function, I was inspired to come up with my own variant.  I came up with one that is simpler than any of the variants listed here so far.  It basically uses two semaphores, normal synchronization, and an array:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class ArrayBlockingSemQueue<T> implements BlockQueue<T>
{
    private final int capacity;
    private final Semaphore notEmpty;
    private final Semaphore notFull;
    private final Object [] items;
    int takeIndex;
    int putIndex;

    public ArrayBlockingSemQueue(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        notEmpty = new Semaphore(0);
        notFull  = new Semaphore(capacity);
        items = new Object[capacity];
    }

    public void add(T t) throws InterruptedException {
        notFull.acquire();

        synchronized(notFull) {
            items[putIndex++] = t;
            if (putIndex == capacity)
                putIndex = 0;
        }

        notEmpty.release();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        T ret;

        notEmpty.acquire();

        synchronized(notEmpty) {
            ret = (T) items[takeIndex++];
            if (takeIndex == capacity)
                takeIndex = 0;
        }

        notFull.release();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

### Benchmarks

I used the same code that @rolfl listed in his answer to test the timings of the various Queues.  Here are my results:

```
           1x1   2x2   3x3   4x4   6x6   12x12 1x12  2x6   3x4   4x3   6x2   12x1
Veritas    3.32  3.39  3.54  3.59  3.54  3.62  6.63  3.95  3.67  3.68  3.88  6.16
DoubleSync 3.72  4.97  4.87  4.94  5.07  4.78  5.43  5.01  4.96  4.93  5.01  5.41
CDLatch    2.89  2.56  4.62  5.02  5.83  8.01  8.25  5.95  5.24  3.60  2.58  2.65
JS1        3.05  3.00  3.18  3.08  3.04  3.09  3.47  3.13  3.26  3.07  3.00  3.15
```

Comment: its not a typo, please see LinkedBlockingQueue Implementation. There are no unnecessary signaling, instead its a good design where consumer thread only signals the producer thread only when the queue is full, else unblocking of threads is clearly taken care by producer thread. Also AtomicInteger takes care memory ordering especially happens before relationship so no visibility problem there. See LinkedBlockingQueue impl u will understand what i am talking

Comment: So as such all three of your observations are wrong. anyways thanks for reviewing it carefully

Comment: @veritas It **is** a typo.  Read the LinkedBlockingQueue `put` function.  You will see.  I'm referring to the empty vs full.  You may be right about the signalling being ok.

Comment: @yahh am sorry i was looking at the add function

Comment: @veritas Sorry for the incorrect review.  I have now updated the answer to account for the things that you pointed out.  Seems like I have a lot to learn about Java!

Comment: @veritas I updated my answer with a new implementation.  Maybe you could look it over and see whether it works for you or if I missed anything?

Comment: thanks would love continue on that, right now busy will catch up in my free time .. thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Simplified code

In order to understand your code, I copied it out, and simplified it by:

1. removing redundant variables (why do you take copies of private-final fields in your methods?) The following code is particularly bizarre:

   > ```
   > final AtomicInteger count = this.count;
   > ```
2. ... there was going to be another thing, but then I realized I was wrong...

OK, is your code thread safe? Yes, I believe so. It is horribly complicated, though....

You have tagged your question as [lock-free](/questions/tagged/lock-free)... it obviously is not lock-free. You have multiple locks. What's more, is that it is overly-locked.

Additionally, I predict the performance in a concurrent situation will be much worse than you expect. Note that, for the typical put/take, you do 4 locking operations, and two atomic operations

1. lock the put/tack Lock
2. atomic get on the count
3. atomic update the count
4. unlock the lock
5. lock the other lock
6. signal the other lock
7. unlock the other lock.

Atomic operations are fast, but they are not free. Additionally, since you are using the same atomic count in both the put and get, and also, since both put, and take lock both `putLock` and `takeLock` (and access count), you are not actually accomplishing the stated goal of *"i.e using two locks so that my take should not block my put."*

Your take does block your put, and visa-versa.

In my experience, the value of `ReentrantLock` is not related to the fact that it is in the concurrent package and "new", it is in the fact that the cost of a double-barrier (lock/unlock) when amortized over a long-running piece of code (which your code is not), is worth it for the cool features (like multiple signals on one lock instance, or in-the-middle-of-execution unlocking). You do neither of those things. Your use of the ReentrantLock is basically just slowing you down, and making your code complicated.

Additionally, what you see as an 'optimization' for only notifying the other method if there is something new, is actually just slowing things down too.

Your code would be simpler, and faster, and more concurrent with traditional synchronization...

```
public class ArrayBlockingSyncQueue<T> {

    private final Object [] items ;
    private int takeIndex;
    private int size;

    public ArrayBlockingSyncQueue(int capacity) {
        items = new Object[capacity];
    }

    public void add(T t) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(items) {
            while (size == items.length) {
                items.wait();
            }
            int putIndex = (takeIndex + size) % items.length;
            items[putIndex] = t;
            size++;
            items.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(items) {
            while (size == 0) {
                items.wait();
            }
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            T t = (T)items[takeIndex];
            items[takeIndex] = null; //for GC
            takeIndex++;
            size--;
            if (takeIndex >= items.length) {
                takeIndex = 0;
            }
            items.notifyAll();
            return t;
        }
    }

}
```

### Not Fast Enough - BENCHMARKS

**UPDATE**: After benchmarking your code, against my suggestion above, I found your code was faster than I expected. This runs against my experience with Locks, which I have, in the past, found to be slower than synchronization due to the double-lock process (lock barrier going in, and again when coming out).

I was expecting the plain-jane synchronzation to out-perform the complciated locking, and I was wrong. So, I investigated, and have the following thoughts on the results:

1. your strategy is faster than the single-sync because the access-loop is so tight in my testing, that all threads are locked on a single monitor. Your locking is locked on 2, so, even though your individual locking is slower than synchronization, it's still doing 2 threads at once, not one.
2. double-entry synchronization should still be faster than the locks, in a tight loop.
3. the test is essentially invalid, because there is no job out there which does nothing except feed, or empty a queue. All real jobs do something before giving, or after taking the data, and in a typical situation, the actual time in the queue should be almost negligible.

So, based on the above, I implemented a collection of benchmarks using the following strategies:

1. build an interface of the add/take methods on your queue called `BlockingQueue`
2. build a tight-loop putter-thread, and a tight-loop taker thread. They look like:

   > ```
   > private final int runPuts(int id) throws InterruptedException {
   >     long waiting = 0;
   >     int base = id * count;
   >     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   >         queue.add(base + i);
   >     }
   >     return count;
   > }
   >
   > private final long runGets() {
   >     long sum = 0;
   >     try {
   >         while (true) {
   >             Integer got = queue.take();
   >             if (got == POISON) {
   >                 break;
   >             }
   >             sum += got;
   >         }
   >     } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
   >         ie.printStackTrace();
   >     }
   >     return sum;
   > }
   > ```
3. Have multiple threads putting values, and taking values. Each value put on to the queue is unique (it is the `thread-ID * count-per-thread + i`) The if all the values are removed from the queue, then added up, the sum should be predictable, and is a good test to ensure that every value added to the queue is also removed from it. Any error should be immediately obvious if the sum is wrong.
4. Run the same test for multiple implementations of BlockingQueue, at multiple different combinations of Producers and Consumers.

What were the results? Comparing the above single-monitor synchronization with your double-locked implementation, using 20-capacity queues, and passing 12,000 values through, the results are:

```
               1x1,   2x2,   3x3,   4x4,   6x6, 12x12,  1x12,   2x6,   3x4,   4x3,   6x2,  12x1
    Veritas, 2.267, 5.659, 3.349, 3.884, 3.599, 4.256, 4.931, 4.970, 4.216, 3.490, 6.699, 6.582
 SingleSync, 3.773, 3.111, 4.057, 4.551, 5.440, 6.894, 5.813, 3.276, 4.435, 5.012, 4.519, 4.691
```

Note a few things in there.... my Computer is a 4-core i7, and it has slow performance on your locking when there's 4 threads at 100% (two producers,  2 consumers). Something 'odd' happens then. The rest of the time it is fairly predictable.

The single-sync code is slower than yours for simple cases, but starts performing better than yours under high thread imbalance - where there are many more consumers than producers, or the other way.

### Double-ended Synchronization

Still, the results are interesting for their variance.... but, what if I used a similar double-ended synchronization system to your double-ended locks? What would happen then?

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class ArrayBlockingSyncDeQueue<T> implements BlockQueue<T>{

    private final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0); 
    private final Object putLock = new Object();
    private final Object takeLock = new Object();
    private final Object [] items;
    int takeIndex;
    int putIndex;

    public ArrayBlockingSyncDeQueue(int capacity) {
        items = new Object[capacity];
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T t) throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized(putLock) {
            while (count.get() == items.length) {
                putLock.wait();
            }
            items[putIndex] = t;
            putIndex++;
            putIndex %= items.length;
            int used = count.incrementAndGet();
            if (used < items.length) {
                putLock.notify();
            }
            if (used > 1) {
                // no need to notify takers.
                // just exit.
                return;
            }

        }
        synchronized(takeLock) {
            takeLock.notify();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        boolean notify = false;
        try {
            synchronized(takeLock) {
                while (count.get() == 0) {
                    takeLock.wait();
                }
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                T t = (T) items[takeIndex];
                items[takeIndex] = null;
                takeIndex++;
                takeIndex %= items.length;
                int used = count.getAndDecrement();
                if (used == items.length) {
                    notify = true;
                }
                if (used > 1) {
                    takeLock.notify();
                }
                return t;
            }
        } finally {
            if (notify) {
                synchronized (putLock) {
                    putLock.notify();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Well,t hat is essentially always faster than the Reentrant lock system of yours:

```
               1x1,   2x2,   3x3,   4x4,   6x6, 12x12,  1x12,   2x6,   3x4,   4x3,   6x2,  12x1
    Veritas, 2.267, 5.659, 3.349, 3.884, 3.599, 4.256, 4.931, 4.970, 4.216, 3.490, 6.699, 6.582
 DoubleSync, 1.680, 3.497, 3.451, 3.585, 5.465, 3.627, 4.738, 3.398, 4.432, 4.030, 4.241, 4.071
 SingleSync, 3.773, 3.111, 4.057, 4.551, 5.440, 6.894, 5.813, 3.276, 4.435, 5.012, 4.519, 4.691
```

### Java library

But, how would this compare to the standard Java Concurrent library (which has the BlockingQueues too)?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class ConcBlockingArrayQueue<T> implements BlockQueue<T> {

    private final BlockingQueue<T> q;

    public ConcBlockingArrayQueue(int capacity) {
        q = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(capacity);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T t) throws InterruptedException {
        q.put(t);
    }

    @Override
    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        return q.take();
    }

}
```

and

```
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class ConcBlockingLinkedQueue<T> implements BlockQueue<T> {

    private final BlockingQueue<T> q;

    public ConcBlockingLinkedQueue(int capacity) {
        q = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(capacity);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T t) throws InterruptedException {
        q.put(t);
    }

    @Override
    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        return q.take();
    }

}
```

Well, the Linked one is fast, the Array one is slow....

```
               1x1,   2x2,   3x3,   4x4,   6x6, 12x12,  1x12,   2x6,   3x4,   4x3,   6x2,  12x1
    Veritas, 2.267, 5.659, 3.349, 3.884, 3.599, 4.256, 4.931, 4.970, 4.216, 3.490, 6.699, 6.582
 DoubleSync, 1.680, 3.497, 3.451, 3.585, 5.465, 3.627, 4.738, 3.398, 4.432, 4.030, 4.241, 4.071
 SingleSync, 3.773, 3.111, 4.057, 4.551, 5.440, 6.894, 5.813, 3.276, 4.435, 5.012, 4.519, 4.691
 ConcLinked, 2.982, 5.078, 3.463, 3.634, 3.658, 3.966, 4.353, 5.867, 3.362, 3.536, 3.572, 4.375
  ConcArray, 3.045, 3.246, 6.018, 5.377, 5.586, 6.207,23.079, 6.781, 6.544, 6.924, 6.609,12.136
```

### Lock Free (for real this time).

But, finally, what if we actually did use a Lock-free implementation? Using no locks, just semaphores, and atomics?

Here's the preview:

```
               1x1,   2x2,   3x3,   4x4,   6x6, 12x12,  1x12,   2x6,   3x4,   4x3,   6x2,  12x1
    Veritas, 2.267, 5.659, 3.349, 3.884, 3.599, 4.256, 4.931, 4.970, 4.216, 3.490, 6.699, 6.582
   LockFree, 2.797, 2.884, 2.951, 3.076, 3.391, 3.461, 3.186, 3.176, 2.901, 3.225, 3.602, 4.186
 DoubleSync, 1.680, 3.497, 3.451, 3.585, 5.465, 3.627, 4.738, 3.398, 4.432, 4.030, 4.241, 4.071
 SingleSync, 3.773, 3.111, 4.057, 4.551, 5.440, 6.894, 5.813, 3.276, 4.435, 5.012, 4.519, 4.691
 ConcLinked, 2.982, 5.078, 3.463, 3.634, 3.658, 3.966, 4.353, 5.867, 3.362, 3.536, 3.572, 4.375
  ConcArray, 3.045, 3.246, 6.018, 5.377, 5.586, 6.207,23.079, 6.781, 6.544, 6.924, 6.609,12.136
```

Lock Free is consistently performing faster than the alternatives when more than one thread is accessing either end. 25% faster would be about the right ballpark.

Here's the lock-free code. Note, instead of using an array, it uses a linked list (calling it an `ArrayBlockingAtomQueue` is a bad name - I agree):

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class ArrayBlockingAtomQueue<T> implements BlockQueue<T>{

    private static final class Node<U> {

        private U val;
        private AtomicReference<Node<U>> next = new AtomicReference<>();
        private AtomicBoolean owned = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        public Node(U val) {
            super();
            this.val = val;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            Node<U> n = next.get();
            return String.format("Node Value %s next %s", val, n == null ? "---" : n.val);
        }

    }

    private final AtomicReference<Node<T>> head = new AtomicReference<>();
    private final AtomicReference<Node<T>> tail = new AtomicReference<>();
    private final Semaphore slot;
    private final Semaphore waiting;

    private final Node<T> sentry = new Node<>(null);
//    private final Node<T> empty = new Node<>(null, null);

    public ArrayBlockingAtomQueue(int capacity) {
        slot = new Semaphore(capacity);
        waiting = new Semaphore(0);
//        empty.next.set(empty);
        sentry.owned.set(true);
        head.set(sentry);
        tail.set(sentry);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T t) throws InterruptedException {

        // space, or wait till there is.
        slot.acquire();

        final Node<T> node = new Node<>(t);

        Node<T> back = tail.getAndSet(node);
        if (!back.next.compareAndSet(null, node)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Tail node's next was already set");
        }
        waiting.release();
    }

    @Override
    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        // data, or wait till there is.
        waiting.acquire();
        // we know a bunch of read threads may be scanning the list.
        // the head node may not yet be set with data, but we know it is coming.
        Node<T> mine = null;
        do {
            Node<T> h = head.get();
            while (h != null) {
                if (h.owned.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                    mine = h;
                    break;
                }
                Node<T> n = h.next.get();
                if (n != null) {
                    // advance the head past processed items 
                    head.compareAndSet(h,n);
                }
                h = h.next.get();
            }
        } while (mine == null);

        //waiting.release();
        slot.release();
        T value = mine.val;
        mine.val = null;
        return value;
    }

}
```

### Count Down Latch option

The previous atomic/link free code has an issue with the sentry node... it should not be a field variable, as a result, it is holding a reference to the entire chain of nodes... and that's a problem for the Garbage Collector. Fixing it made it significantly slower... for a reason I am unsure of. As a result, have worked it out yet another way, using a `CountDownLatch`:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;

@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class LinkBlockingAtomQueue<T> implements BlockQueue<T>{

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static final class Node<U> extends AtomicBoolean{

        private U val;
        private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        private Node<U> next = null;

        public Node(U val) {
            this.val = val;
        }

    }

    private final AtomicReference<Node<T>> head = new AtomicReference<>();
    private final AtomicReference<Node<T>> tail = new AtomicReference<>();
    private final Semaphore putSlot;

    public LinkBlockingAtomQueue(int capacity) {

        putSlot = new Semaphore(capacity);

        // prime the head with a 'done' node which we can
        // append to in the put methods.
        Node<T> sentry = new Node<>(null);
        sentry.set(true);
        head.set(sentry);
        tail.set(sentry);
    }

    @Override
    public void add(T t) throws InterruptedException {

        final Node<T> node = new Node<>(t);
        // space, or wait till there is.
        putSlot.acquire();
        Node<T> back = tail.getAndSet(node);
        back.next = node;
        back.latch.countDown();
    }

    @Override
    public T take() throws InterruptedException {
        // we know a bunch of read threads may be scanning the list.
        // the head node may not yet be set with data, but we know it is coming.
        try {
            Node<T> current = head.get();
            while (!current.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
                current.latch.await();
                head.compareAndSet(current, current.next);
                current = current.next;
            }
            T ret = current.val;
            current.val = null;
            return ret;
        } finally {
            putSlot.release();
        }
    }

}
```

Running the CountDownLatch code with the previous LockFree code, and the `Veritas` original, I get the following results (Note they were run at a different time to other results in this post, and are not comparable with them).

```
MILLISECONDS,   1x1,   2x2,   3x3,   4x4,   6x6, 12x12,  1x12,   2x6,   3x4,   4x3,   6x2,  12x1
     Veritas, 1.648, 3.370, 3.042, 3.334, 3.459, 3.681, 1.513, 1.758, 3.299, 3.314, 3.495, 2.944
    LockFree, 1.537, 2.420, 2.916, 2.960, 3.111, 3.396, 3.013, 2.996, 2.849, 2.816, 2.938, 2.497
     CDLatch, 0.969, 2.082, 2.553, 2.956, 3.465, 5.619, 5.520, 3.019, 2.820, 2.628, 2.557, 2.107
```

### Conclusion

The bottom line is that the double-ended synchronization is faster than the double-ended locking.... as I would expect. Faster yet is a lock-free system that's not using an array at all, but that may be a 'cheat'. Still, compared to the native Java library offerings, both the array-based, and link-based options can be beaten... handily.

Comment: I agree with the redundancy point i too don't like it. but i try to  code in a similar fashion to LBQ so that people don't have problem in comparison. also see some arguments in favour of this style here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28975415/why-jdk-code-style-uses-a-variable-assignment-and-read-on-the-same-line-eg-i

Comment: signalling the other lock only when the queue is empty or full. not on any other attempt. you code on the other hand signals every time. and consider the worst case scenario .. when the consumer is very slow so that the queue is full almost every time and producer threads are blocked.  Your notifyAll wakes all the thread each eating more cpu.

Comment: think of this scenario one producer Thread and 10 consumer threads. A single producer thread had fight with other 10 threads to get the lock. Whereas in my code producer thread isn't contented at all except when the queue is empty.  And Empty queue is always a happy scenario  means you overall performance is anyways great. This tradeoff increases the throughput for the writer/producer threads.

Comment: the code is not the same but the idea is please see http://www.research.ibm.com/people/m/michael/podc-1996.pdf

Comment: Probably throughput of two-lock implementation will be better under high contention scenarios in comparison to single lock. But yes agreed there may be scenarios where the opposite is true

Comment: @veritas - my experience indicates otherwise. I will test it later today to show you. I expect the plain-sync system to at least double-the-throughput of your version.

Comment: @veritas - my results are preliminary, but it looks like I may have to "eat crow" soon.... yours is faster, though that breaks some of my mental models... I am trying to reconcile/figure things out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23002/discussion-between-rolfl-and-js1).

Comment: @rolfl Hi, I updated my answer with my own implementation.  Could you plug it into your test framework and verify that I didn't mess anything up?

Comment: @rofl  yahh sure will discuss offline . kinda busy now will catch up later.